# Access to XML prefixes in WCF

Tags: xml, wcf, xaml, soap

I am trying to pass several XAML document fragments to a SOAP `basicHttpBinding` web service as `XElement` instances.

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "someNamespace")]
interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Start(XElement someArgument);
}
```

The messages end up with a format like below.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:exec="someNamespace"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <exec:Start>
         <exec:someArgument>
            <SomeObject xmlns="someAnotherNamespace"
                        xmlns:myPrefix="yetAnotherNamespace">
               <AnotherObject Property="{myPrefix:Foo}" />
            </SomeObject>
         </exec:someArgument>
      </exec:Start>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

All is well is `myPrefix` is defined on the root of the XAML island (i.e. `<SomeObject>`). However, if I move the namespace declaration to the `<soapenv:Envelope>` (which is obviously permitted, barring any prefix clashes)

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:exec="someNamespace"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:myPrefix="yetAnotherNamespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <exec:Start>
         <exec:someArgument>
            <SomeObject xmlns="someAnotherNamespace">
               <AnotherObject Property="{myPrefix:Foo}" />
            </SomeObject>
         </exec:someArgument>
      </exec:Start>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The resulting `XElement` no longer has knowledge about that the URI `yetAnotherNamespace` is actually represented by the prefix `myPrefix`. Instead, a generic prefix (`p2`) is assigned.

Therefore, `XamlXmlReader` will be unable to read the markup extension `{myPrefix:Foo}`, since it is still associated with the old prefix `myPrefix` instead of `p2`. Indeed, for XML processing inside of WCF, the markup extension was a string attribute, and received no specific treatment for namespace prefixes.

The behavior in which successful reading of the XML island depends on the placement of `xmlns:` prefix declarations is highly confusing. *Is there a way to re-map prefixes somehow for more correct behavior?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Playing around a bit I realized that if I use `XmlElement` instead of `XElement`, the problem goes away, as the original prefixes are all kept. However, I am still curious whether a more elegant solution exists...</strike>

Unfortunately, reverting from `System.Xml.Linq` to `System.Xml` does not help, because if a namespace prefix is only used in markup extensions (not tags), its prefix will be unrecoverable. Instead, I implemented an `IDispatchMessageInspector`, which redeclares the namespaces on selected XML elements inside the SOAP envelope (inheriting `xmlns:` declarations from the whole envelope) in order to make a selected fragment of the XML self-contained.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace RedeclareNamespaces
{
    internal class RedeclareNamespacesMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector, IEndpointBehavior
    {
        private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<string> actionFilters;
        private readonly IXmlNamespaceResolver namespaceResolver;
        private readonly string targetElements;

        public RedeclareNamespacesMessageInspector(IReadOnlyCollection<string> actionFilters,
            IXmlNamespaceResolver namespaceResolver, string targetElements)
        {
            this.actionFilters = actionFilters;
            this.namespaceResolver = namespaceResolver;
            this.targetElements = targetElements;
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            if (ShouldProcessRequest(request))
                DoAfterReceiveRequest(ref request);
            return null;
        }

        private bool ShouldProcessRequest(Message request)
        {
            return actionFilters == null || actionFilters.Contains(request.Headers.Action);
        }

        private void DoAfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request)
        {
            var document = ReadXDocument(request);
            RedeclareNamespaces(document);
            var xmlReader = CreateMessageXmlReader(document);
            request = Message.CreateMessage(xmlReader, int.MaxValue, request.Headers.MessageVersion);
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            // Nothing to fix here.
        }

        private static XDocument ReadXDocument(Message request)
        {
            // A buffered copy of the message must be created before the whole envelope can be read.
            var buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
            var copyOfRequest = buffer.CreateMessage();

            var document = new XDocument();
            using (var writer = document.CreateWriter())
            {
                copyOfRequest.WriteMessage(writer);
                writer.Flush();
            }
            return document;
        }

        private void RedeclareNamespaces(XDocument document)
        {
            var elementsToFix = document.XPathSelectElements(targetElements, namespaceResolver);
            foreach (var element in elementsToFix)
            {
                var inheritedXmlnsAttributes = GetInheritedXmlnsAttributes(element);
                element.Add(inheritedXmlnsAttributes);
            }
        }

        private object[] GetInheritedXmlnsAttributes(XElement targetElement)
        {
            var prefixesSeen = new HashSet<string>();
            var attributes = new List<object>();
            var element = targetElement;
            while (element != null)
            {
                for (var attribute = element.FirstAttribute; attribute != null; attribute = attribute.NextAttribute)
                {
                    string localName = attribute.Name.LocalName;
                    if (!attribute.IsNamespaceDeclaration || prefixesSeen.Contains(localName))
                        continue;
                    prefixesSeen.Add(localName);
                    // Do not add attributes declared on the element itself twice, but mark them as seen.
                    if (element != targetElement)
                        attributes.Add(new XAttribute(attribute));
                }
                element = element.Parent;
            }
            return attributes.ToArray();
        }

        private static XmlReader CreateMessageXmlReader(XDocument document)
        {
            // Do not dispose this XmlReader and Stream before the message is consumed.
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            // We must save the message into a buffer, directly reading the XDocument nodes is not supported by WCF.
            document.Save(stream, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            return xmlReader;
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            // Nothing to do.
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            // Nothing to do.
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            // Nothing to do.
        }
    }

    public class RedeclareNamespacesConfigurationSection : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        private const string ActionFilterAttribute = "actionFilter";

        [ConfigurationProperty(ActionFilterAttribute)]
        public string ActionFilter
        {
            get { return (string) this[ActionFilterAttribute]; }
            set { this[ActionFilterAttribute] = value; }
        }

        private const string NamespacesAttribute = "namespaces";

        [ConfigurationProperty(NamespacesAttribute)]
        public string Namespaces
        {
            get { return (string)this[NamespacesAttribute]; }
            set { this[NamespacesAttribute] = value; }
        }

        private const string TargetElementsAttribute = "targetElements";

        [ConfigurationProperty(TargetElementsAttribute)]
        public string TargetElements
        {
            get { return (string)this[TargetElementsAttribute]; }
            set { this[TargetElementsAttribute] = value; }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            var actionFilters = ActionFilter?.Split(';').Select(i => i.Trim()).ToArray();
            var namespaceResolver = CreateNamespaceResolver();
            if (TargetElements == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(TargetElementsAttribute, "TargetElements query must be provided.");
            return new RedeclareNamespacesMessageInspector(actionFilters, namespaceResolver, TargetElements);
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType => typeof(RedeclareNamespacesMessageInspector);

        private XmlNamespaceManager CreateNamespaceResolver()
        {
            var namespaceResolver = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            if (Namespaces != null)
            {
                foreach (var rawDeclaration in Namespaces.Split(';'))
                {
                    var namespaceDeclaration = rawDeclaration.Trim();
                    var index = namespaceDeclaration.IndexOf("=");
                    if (index < 0)
                        throw new ArgumentException("Namespaces must be of the form \"ns1=uri1;ns2=uri2;...\"",
                            NamespacesAttribute);
                    var prefix = namespaceDeclaration.Substring(0, index);
                    var uri = namespaceDeclaration.Substring(index + 1);
                    namespaceResolver.AddNamespace(prefix, uri);
                }
            }
            return namespaceResolver;
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used in App.config as follows.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="redeclareNamespaces"
             type="RedeclareNamespaces.RedeclareNamespacesConfigurationSection,RedeclareNamespaces"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RedeclareNamespacesBehavior">
          <redeclareNamespaces actionFilter="http://myExampleUri/IExampleService/Frobnicate"
                               namespaces="soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/;
                                           myNamespace=http://myExampleUri"
                               targetElements="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body//myNamespace:Frobnicate/myNamespace:xamlArgumentHere/*"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, the message inspector has to copy the whole envelope at least twice: first the `Message` has to be copied to a buffer, then after the transformation the `XDocument` must be saved into the stream. I got some baffling exceptions due to an invalid XML node stream if I passed `document.CreateReader()` to the `Message` constructor directly.